# How to pass json array in to Retrofit POST request

Tags: android, retrofit

I want to pass JSON array inside body in Retrofit.

contacts: [{fullName: "foo", email: "abc@gmail.com", countryCode: "00", phoneNumber: "00000000"}]

This is how I am doing it

```
@FormUrlEncoded @POST("office/templates/send/{id}") 
fun sendTemplates(
    @Header("Authorization") accessToken: String?, 
    @Field("contacts[]") contacts: List<SendDocumentModel>, 
    @Path("id") id: String?):
Call<BaseResponse<TemplatesResponse>>
```

Comment: Hi Taha Imtiaz, can you share what you already done?

Comment: This is how I am trying.

@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("office/templates/send/{id}")
    fun sendTemplates(@Header("Authorization") accessToken: String?,
                      @Field("contacts[]") contacts: List<SendDocumentModel>,
                      @Path("id") id: String?): Call<BaseResponse<TemplatesResponse>>

Comment: Hi Taha, you can Edit your question include the one you comment just now

Answer (score 0):

Change Call< BaseResponse< TemplatesResponse >> to Call< JsonArray > with using the library of com.google.gson.JsonArray